# How to call Facebook auth.getSession (REST API) method using OAuth token?

Tags: facebook, rest, oauth

Issue is about interactions between *Facebook REST* and *Graph API* .

I'm building a Facebook application. Once I have a valid OAuth access token I try to incloke *auth.getSession* method by accessing the URL

http://api.facebook.com/method/auth.getSession?access_token=...

and I get back errors like this

```
<error_response xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd">
  <error_code>100</error_code>
  <error_msg>The parameter auth_token is required</error_msg>
  <request_args list="true">...</request_args>
</error_response>
```

So I called *auth.createToken* method immediately after that , and token was returned ok . Then I try to call *auth.getSession* once again by accessing this URL:

http://api.facebook.com/method/auth.getSession?auth_token=...

I just get a different error like the one shown below

```
<error_response xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd">
  <error_code>101</error_code>
  <error_msg>Invalid API key</error_msg>
  <request_args list="true">...</request_args>
</error_response>
```

So how could I invoke *auth.getSession* method if I only have a valid *OAuth* token ?

Comment: The same happens if I use pyfacebook library and invoke `Facebook.auth.getSession` instance method.